# How to read cookie value in MVC 5 application startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, localization, startup

I have an application in MVC5 with localization support. I have used routing to store current language value.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

On the other hand, I store current culture value in the cookies for later use. I want to read the culture value from cookies every time user wants to start browsing my application and set his language based on cookie values. After this stage, I will store language parameters in the route values.

How can I read and set language from cookies at application Startup?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. Which cookies are you talking about? There is no HttpContext available at "application startup", so nowhere to get these cookies from.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you would be able to read cookies on Application Startup, because it still has not loaded the `HttpContext`.

Once you set up the `HttpContext` you will be able to read cookies from it

When controller factory is invoked it loads `RequestContext`, then it attaches to it `HttpContext`, you may inject your own controller factory in order to hook in the context, before the controller is instantiated, but I am not sure if it does worth at all.

My suggestion would be to override the `OnActionExecuting()` method in your base controller, so you will check the cookies there. You can reach them by accessing `this.Request.Cookies` within the method, or if it's still not populated you may reach the `RequestContext` from the passed `ActionExecutingContext` object.